# How to collect selected BootstrapVue (b-form-checkbox) check boxes?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I work on Nuxt.js (Vue.js) application and modal dialog looks as following:

[image]

The code of Basket.vue component looks as following:

```
<template lang="pug">
  b-container(v-if='products.length > 0')
    b-row
      b-col(:cols="8")
        b-container
          b-row
            b-list-group
              b-list-group-item.flex-column.align-items-start(v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="index")
                b-container
                  b-row
                    b-col(:cols="1").d-flex.align-items-center.justify-content-center
                      b-form-checkbox {{ index + 1 }}
                    b-col(:cols="11")
                      basket-item(:product="product")
          b-row.row-middle-style
            b-button.close(type='button' aria-label='Close' @click="onRemoveItem")
              span(aria-hidden='true') &times;
                u Remove selected items
            b-button(type='button' @click="onContinue()").btn.btn-lg.buy__button Продолжить покупки
          b-row
            div
              hr
              | * доставка будет осуществлена из Санкт-Петербурга;
              br
              | * наш менеджер свяжется с вами сразу после обработки заказа;
  ...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import BasketItem from './BasketItem.vue'
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
    BasketItem,
  },
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['products']),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      onRemoveItem: 'removeItem',
    }),
  },
})
</script>

<style lang="sass">
  ...
</style>
```

The code of BasketItem.vue component looks as following:

```
<template lang="pug">
  b-container
    b-row.style-item-row
      b-col(:cols="3")
        img(:src="product.image" :alt="product.alt")
      b-col(:cols="4")
        div {{ product.name }}
        div {{ product.description }}
      b-col(:cols="4")
        div Цена {{ product.price }}
        div Количество {{ product.quantity }}
      b-col(:cols="1")
        b-button.close(type='button' aria-label='Close' @click="onRemoveItem(product.id)")
          span(aria-hidden='true') &times;
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      onRemoveItem: 'removeItem',
    }),
  },
})
</script>

<style lang="sass">
  ...
</style>
```

The Vuex code looks as following:

```
import * as mutationTypes from './mutation_types'

export const state = () => ({
  products: [
    {
      id: 1,
      image: 'https://licota.ru/system/product_images/attachments/5d9b/1781/6332/3406/9d00/2a31/small/8bfa7c2c-c7c7-11e4-80f4-002590d99cf6.jpg?1570445184',
      alt: 'Товар 1',
      name: 'Товар 1',
      description: 'Описание 1',
      price: 100,
      quantity: 4
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      image: 'https://licota.ru/system/product_images/attachments/5d9b/329f/6332/3406/9d00/9336/small/e6a69bba-3450-11e9-812c-002590d99cf6.jpg?1570452124',
      alt: 'Товар 2',
      name: 'Товар 2',
      description: 'Описание 2',
      price: 200,
      quantity: 7
    }
  ]
})

export const getters = {
}

export const actions = {
  removeItem({ commit }, id) {
    commit(mutationTypes.REMOVE_ITEM, id)
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  [mutationTypes.REMOVE_ITEM] (state, id) {
    state.products = state.products.filter(x => {
      return x.id != id
    })
  }
}
```

As you can see I have a list of items (there are two). In front of each of them is BootstrapVue (b-form-checkbox) check box. I can select any of them and click "Remove selected items". After that they will be removed. The code for that action doesn't exist at this moment. The Vuex code you can see refers to clicking "x" in upper-right corner of items.

My issue is how to collect selected items that is check boxes that are checked in order to remove appropriate items?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried you'd suggested, but it doesn't work. The most likely I did something wrong. **Actually, when I take a look at Vue section in DevTools, isChecked computed property doesn't change after clicking check boxes.** The code looks as following:

Basket.vue:

```
<template lang="pug">
  b-container(v-if='products.length > 0')
    b-row
      b-col(:cols="8")
        b-container
          b-row
            b-list-group
              b-list-group-item.flex-column.align-items-start(
                v-for="(product, index) in products"
                :key="product.id"
                v-bind="{...product}"
                v-on="{'update:checked': (data) => handleSetChecked(data)}"
              )
                b-container.set_pad
                  b-row
                    b-col(:cols="12").d-flex.align-items-center.justify-content-center
                      basket-item(:product="product" :productIndex="index")
          b-row.row-middle-style
            b-button.close(type='button' aria-label='Close' @click="onRemoveSelectedItems")
              span(aria-hidden='true') &times;
                u Удалить выбранное
            b-button(type='button' @click="onContinue()").btn.btn-lg.buy__button Продолжить покупки
          b-row
            div
              hr
              | * доставка будет осуществлена из Санкт-Петербурга;
              br
              | * наш менеджер свяжется с вами сразу после обработки заказа;
  ...
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import BasketItem from './BasketItem.vue'
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
    BasketItem,
  },
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    products() {
      return this.$store.getters.getProducts
    },
    toRemove() {
      return this.$store.getters.getProductsToRemove
    },
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      onRemoveItem: 'removeItem',
    }),
    handleSetChecked(data) {
      this.$store.dispatch("setToRemove", data)
    },
    handleRemoveItems() {
      this.$store.dispatch("removeSelected")
    },
    onRemoveSelectedItems() {
      this.handleRemoveItems()
    },
  },
})
</script>
```

BasketItem.vue:

```
<template lang="pug">
  b-container
    b-row.style-item-row
      b-col(:cols="1").d-flex.align-items-center.justify-content-center
        b-form-checkbox(v-model="isChecked") {{ productIndex + 1 }}
      b-col(:cols="3")
        img(:src="product.image" :alt="product.alt")
      b-col(:cols="3")
        div {{ product.title }}
        div {{ product.description }}
      b-col(:cols="4")
        div Цена {{ product.price }}
        div Количество {{ product.quantity }}
      b-col(:cols="1")
        b-button.close(type='button' aria-label='Close' @click="onRemoveItem(product.id)")
          span(aria-hidden='true') &times;
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object,
    },
    productIndex: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    isChecked: {
      get() {
        return this.product.checked
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit("update:checked", {
          id: this.product.id,
          checked: val,
        })
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      onRemoveItem: 'removeItem',
    }),
  },
})
</script>
```

Vuex:

```
import * as mutationTypes from './mutation_types'

export const state = () => ({
  products: [
    {
      id: 1,
      image: 'https://licota.ru/system/product_images/attachments/5d9b/1781/6332/3406/9d00/2a31/small/8bfa7c2c-c7c7-11e4-80f4-002590d99cf6.jpg?1570445184',
      alt: 'Товар 1',
      title: 'Товар 1',
      description: 'Описание 1',
      price: 100,
      quantity: 4,
      checked: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      image: 'https://licota.ru/system/product_images/attachments/5d9b/329f/6332/3406/9d00/9336/small/e6a69bba-3450-11e9-812c-002590d99cf6.jpg?1570452124',
      alt: 'Товар 2',
      title: 'Товар 2',
      description: 'Описание 2',
      price: 200,
      quantity: 7,
      checked: false
    }
  ]
})

export const getters = {
  getProducts: state => state.products,
  getProductsToRemove: state => state.products.filter(({
    checked
  }) => checked),
}

export const actions = {
  setToRemove({
    commit
  }, data) {
    commit("SET_TO_REMOVE", data)
  },
  removeSelected({
    commit
  }) {
    commit("REMOVE_SELECTED")
  },
  removeItem({ commit }, id) {
    commit(mutationTypes.REMOVE_ITEM, id)
  },
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_TO_REMOVE(state, {
    id,
    checked
  }) {
    state.products = state.products.map(product => {
      if (product.id === id) {
        return {
          ...product,
          checked,
        }
      } else {
        return product
      }
    })
  },
  REMOVE_SELECTED(state) {
    state.products = state.products.filter(({
      checked
    }) => !checked)
  },
  [mutationTypes.REMOVE_ITEM] (state, id) {
    state.products = state.products.filter(x => {
      return x.id != id
    })
  },
}
```

The reference to "Form Checkbox Inputs":

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to think through your code, and have the logic steps ready:

1. You put out a list of UI items, based on a list in the Vuex store
2. Each UI item has a toggle (checkbox) that sets some part of the state of the item it displays (should it be removed or not)
3. By clicking the toggle (checkbox), the state of the item should change
4. By clicking the button (remove), the Vuex state should change: remove every item whose state fulfills a condition (it's `toRemove` state is `true`)

That's all. More simply put: don't work by selecting some UI element. Work by updating the state of the data that the UI element is based upon. (And let Vue's reactive capability do the rest.)

The first snippet is an easy one, not using **Vuex**:

```js
Vue.component('RowWithCb', {
  props: ["id", "title", "checked"],
  computed: {
    isChecked: {
      get() {
        return this.checked
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit("update:checked", val)
      }
    },
  },
  template: `
    <b-row>
      <b-col
        class="d-flex"
      >
        <div>
          <b-checkbox
            v-model="isChecked"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          {{ title }}
        </div>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  `
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    toRemove() {
      return this.rows.filter(({
        checked
      }) => checked)
    },
    toKeep() {
      return this.rows.filter(({
        checked
      }) => !checked)
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      rows: [{
          id: 1,
          title: "Row 1",
          checked: false,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Row 2",
          checked: false,
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  template: `
    <b-container>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <h3>Items:</h3>
          <row-with-cb
            v-for="row in rows"
            :key="row.id"
            v-bind="{
             ...row
            }"
            :checked.sync="row.checked"
          />
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
      <hr />
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <h4>To keep:</h4>
          {{ toKeep }}
        </b-col>
        <b-col>
          <h4>To remove:</h4>
          {{ toRemove }}
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  `
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

### NOW WITH VUEX

```js
const initialState = () => ({
  rows: [{
      id: 1,
      title: "Row 1",
      checked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Row 2",
      checked: false,
    }
  ]
})

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: initialState(),
  mutations: {
    RESET(state) {
      const init = initialState()
      for (key in init) {
        state[key] = init[key]
      }
    },
    SET_TO_REMOVE(state, {
      id,
      checked
    }) {
      state.rows = state.rows.map(row => {
        if (row.id === id) {
          return {
            ...row,
            checked,
          }
        } else {
          return row
        }
      })
    },
    REMOVE_SELECTED(state) {
      state.rows = state.rows.filter(({
        checked
      }) => !checked)
    },
  },
  actions: {
    reset({
      commit
    }) {
      commit("RESET")
    },
    setToRemove({
      commit
    }, data) {
      commit("SET_TO_REMOVE", data)
    },
    removeSelected({
      commit
    }) {
      commit("REMOVE_SELECTED")
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getRows: state => state.rows,
    getRowsToRemove: state => state.rows.filter(({
      checked
    }) => checked),
    getRowsToKeep: state => state.rows.filter(({
      checked
    }) => !checked),
  }
})

Vue.component('RowWithCb', {
  props: ["id", "title", "checked"],
  computed: {
    isChecked: {
      get() {
        return this.checked
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit("update:checked", {
          id: this.id,
          checked: val,
        })
      }
    },
  },
  template: `
    <b-row>
      <b-col
        class="d-flex"
      >
        <div>
          <b-checkbox
            v-model="isChecked"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          {{ title }}
        </div>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  `
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  computed: {
    rows() {
      return this.$store.getters.getRows
    },
    toRemove() {
      return this.$store.getters.getRowsToRemove
    },
    toKeep() {
      return this.$store.getters.getRowsToKeep
    },
  },
  methods: {
    handleSetChecked(data) {
      this.$store.dispatch("setToRemove", data)
    },
    handleRemoveItems() {
      this.$store.dispatch("removeSelected")
    },
    handleResetStore() {
      this.$store.dispatch("reset")
    },
  },
  template: `
    <b-container>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <h3>Items:</h3>
          <row-with-cb
            v-for="row in rows"
            :key="row.id"
            v-bind="{
             ...row
            }"
            v-on="{
              'update:checked': (data) => handleSetChecked(data)
            }"
          />
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
      <hr />
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <h4>To keep:</h4>
          {{ toKeep }}
        </b-col>
        <b-col>
          <h4>To remove:</h4>
          {{ toRemove }}
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
      <hr />
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <b-button
            @click="handleRemoveItems"
          >
            REMOVE
          </b-button>
          <b-button
            @click="handleResetStore"
          >
            RESET
          </b-button>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  `
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You can see that I did not mess with any checkboxes or UI elements (the only difference is that the `id` is also emitted from the UI component). All the functions were moved to the `Vuex` store & that's all. (A bit more verbose than the first snippet, as I added the remove & the reset functionality.)

---

### LET'S BREAK IT DOWN

#### 1. You need a component that lists items. In this case, let's use the root component for this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      baseItems: [{
          id: "item_1",
          name: "Item 1",
        },
        {
          id: "item_2",
          name: "Item 2",
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.baseItems
    },
  },
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.id"
      >
        {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I deliberately put `items` as `computed` - it's going to be ease to switch to `Vuex`.

#### 2. You know that your listed items are going to be a bit more complex than this, so let's create a `component` that can handle their upcoming complexity:

```js
Vue.component('ListItem', {
  props: ['id', 'name'],
  template: `
    <li>
      {{ name }}
    </li>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      baseItems: [{
          id: "item_1",
          name: "Item 1",
        },
        {
          id: "item_2",
          name: "Item 2",
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.baseItems
    },
  },
  template: `
    <ul>
      <list-item
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.id"
        v-bind="{
          ...item,
        }"
      />
    </ul>
  `
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

#### 3. Let's make them removable - one-by-one or in a bunch:

```js
Vue.component('ListItem', {
  props: ['id', 'name', 'toRemove'],
  computed: {
    selected: {
      get() {
        return this.toRemove
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit('update:to-remove', val)
      }
    },
  },
  template: `
    <li>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        v-model="selected"
      />
      {{ name }}
    </li>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      baseItems: [{
          id: "item_1",
          name: "Item 1",
          toRemove: false,
        },
        {
          id: "item_2",
          name: "Item 2",
          toRemove: false,
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.baseItems
    },
  },
  methods: {
    handleRemoveSelected() {
      this.baseItems = this.baseItems.filter(item => !item.toRemove)
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      So, it's easier to follow:
      {{ items }}
      <hr />
      <ul>
        <list-item
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.id"
          v-bind="{
            ...item,
          }"
          :toRemove.sync="item.toRemove"
        />
      </ul>
      <b-button
        @click="handleRemoveSelected"
      >
        REMOVE SELECTED
      </b-button>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

OK, now there is the function you were after - without `Vuex`

#### 4. Let's mix in `Vuex`:

- move the list to a `Vuex` state
- move the selection to a `Vuex` action
- move the removal to a `Vuex` action

```js
// initial state is a function per Vuex best practices
const initialState = () => ({
  items: [{
      id: "item_1",
      name: "Item 1",
      toRemove: false,
    },
    {
      id: "item_2",
      name: "Item 2",
      toRemove: false,
    }
  ]
})

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: initialState(),
  mutations: {
    // so you are able to reset the store to
    // initial state
    RESET(state) {
      const init = initialState()
      for (key in init) {
        state[key] = init[key]
      }
    },
    // this handles the "checked" state if each item
    SET_TO_REMOVE(state, {
      id,
      toRemove,
    }) {
      // returning a new, modified array
      // per FLUX process
      state.items = state.items.map(item => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            toRemove,
          }
        } else {
          return item
        }
      })
    },
    // the same function that was in the app before
    REMOVE_SELECTED(state) {
      state.items = state.items.filter(({
        toRemove
      }) => !toRemove)
    },
  },
  actions: {
    reset({
      commit
    }) {
      commit("RESET")
    },
    // action to commit the mutation: select item for removal
    setToRemove({
      commit
    }, data) {
      commit("SET_TO_REMOVE", data)
    },
    // action to commit the mutation: remove items
    removeSelected({
      commit
    }) {
      commit("REMOVE_SELECTED")
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getItems: state => state.items,
  }
})

Vue.component('ListItem', {
  props: ['id', 'name', 'toRemove'],
  computed: {
    selected: {
      get() {
        return this.toRemove
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit('update:to-remove', val)
      }
    },
  },
  template: `
    <li>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        v-model="selected"
      />
      {{ name }}
    </li>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  data() {
    return {
      baseItems: [{
          id: "item_1",
          name: "Item 1",
          toRemove: false,
        },
        {
          id: "item_2",
          name: "Item 2",
          toRemove: false,
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.$store.getters.getItems
    },
  },
  methods: {
    handleSetToRemove(data) {
      // data should be: { id, toRemove }
      this.$store.dispatch("setToRemove", data)
    },
    handleRemoveSelected() {
      this.$store.dispatch("removeSelected")
    },
    handleResetStore() {
      this.$store.dispatch("reset")
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      So, it's easier to follow:
      {{ items }}
      <hr />
      <ul>
        <list-item
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.id"
          v-bind="{
            ...item,
          }"
          @update:to-remove="(toRemove) => handleSetToRemove({
            id: item.id,
            toRemove,
          })"
        />
      </ul>
      <b-button
        @click="handleRemoveSelected"
      >
        REMOVE SELECTED
      </b-button>
      <b-button
        @click="handleResetStore"
      >
        RESET
      </b-button>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

This is all there's to it.

1. You handle the selection in the small component - but the change of the selected state is NOT HANDLED inside this component, but emitted to the parent, which in turn handles this by calling a `Vuex` action. This changes the state in the `Vuex` store & that "flows" back through the props.
2. If you click on `REMOVE SELECTED`, that doesn't look at the components (if they are selected), but calls another `Vuex` action, that removes all selected items (by filtering) from the state of the `Vuex` store. As all items are put out from a getter of the `Vuex` store (and getters update if the underlying state changes), the new state appears in the list.

So, in this case, using `Vuex` might seem a bit overkill, but if you plan on a more complex state for the listed items, then it may be reasonable.

Comment: I've tried to apply your approach with Vuex, but it doesn't work. The most likely I did something wrong. Please, take a look at UPDATE section in the original post.

Comment: @tesicg I understand that it's been a week, but I hope I can still help.